# URL shared through facebook is altered when it includes empty square brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a facebook like button, with layout `button_count` which works perfectly in most situations but when the URL being shared contains `[]` it is altering that part of the URL to be `[0]`.

I see the same behaviour with the [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). If I enter the URL `http://example.com?test%5B%5D=1` it gets transformed to `http://example.com/?test%5B0%5D=1` (note the zero that has crept in).

I have tried with the initial URL both escaped and un-escaped with the same results.

I have tried configuring the like button with an `href` attribute and a `data-href` attribute and setting the `og:url` manually all to have escaped and unescaped versions of the URL but it insists on adding the `0` between empty square brackets.

The application that is consuming the URL is a rails application which translates the request parameters to `"test" => { "0" => "1" }` whereas my application is expecting `"test" => ["1"]`.

Any ideas how to get facebook to leave the URL as it is? (I really don't want to have to parse the parameters a different way just for facebook requests - other social media sharing options work okay and leave the URL alone).

Comment: That’s probably due to how Facebook parses URLs internally – after all, most of their code is PHP-based, and PHP and “array” parameters in URLs are a story of their own … I don’t think there is an explicit way around this. You could try and open a bug report for it and see what they say, whether they are willing to fix this. Your other option would be to rewrite such URLs to the format your app requires before they actually “reach” your app.

Comment: Thanks. That was my fear: that it would be entirely within facebook. I'll see if I get any response there and report back.

Comment: (I didn't get a response)